# How to insert an object in an array of object while looping in rails

Tags: arrays, ruby-on-rails, ruby, object

controller.rb

```
def index
 @expenses = Expense.all.order(:expense_type_id)
end
```

@expenses looks like as below

```
[#<Expense:0x00007faeb044c6e8
  id: 1,
  amount: 120
  expense_type_id: 1>,
 #<Expense:0x00007faeb044c2b0
  id: 2,
  amount: 1200
  expense_type_id: 1>,
 #<Expense:0x00007faeb044c2b0
  id: 3,
  amount: 11200
  expense_type_id: 3>,
 #<Expense:0x00007faeb044c2b0
  id: 4,
  amount: 1120
  expense_type_id: 4>,
#<Expense:0x00007faeb044c2b0
  id: 5,
  amount: 1120
  expense_type_id: 4>]
```

index.json.jbuilder

```
json.records do
  json.array! @expenses do |expense|
    json.amount expense.billed
    json.id expense.id
    json.expense_type_id expense.expense_type_id

  end
end
```

Right now the output returned from the index.json.jbuilder file is

```
records = [{amount: 120, id: 1, expense_type_id: 1}, {amount: 1200, id: 2, expense_type_id: 1}, {amount: 11200, id: 3, expense_type_id: 3}, {amount: 1120, id: 4, expense_type_id: 4}, {amount: 1120, id: 5, expense_type_id: 4}]
```

but how I want the output to be is

```
records = [{amount: 120, id: 1, expense_type_id: 1}, {amount: 1200, id: 2, expense_type_id: 1}, {amount: sum of amount with expense_type_id 1, id: 'Subtotal', expense_type_id: nil}, {amount: 11200, id: 3, expense_type_id: 3}, {amount: sum of amount with expense_type_id 3, id: 'Subtotal', expense_type_id: nil}, {amount: 1120, id: 4, expense_type_id: 4}, {amount: 1120, id: 5, expense_type_id: 4}, {amount: sum of amount with expense_type_id 4, id: 'Subtotal', expense_type_id: nil}]
```

I want a Subtotal object to be inserted getting all expenses of each expense_type_id. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The proposed output format seems like it would be more difficult to work with since the type of values is less determinate. Loosely speaking it's changing types for id from ID to "ID || string" and types for expense_type_id from ID to "ID || null".  Is there a reason you can't change the format to maybe be something like:  `expenses_by_type: [{expense_type_id: 1, sub_total: 2000, expenses: [{each expense that is part of this}]} ]`. If needed you could still include a generic un-grouped version too: `expenses: [{id: 1, amount: 120, expense_type_id: 3}, {...}, ]` (or leave for client)

Comment: Would you be open to considering a separate array for the aggregated values? This structure looks like the array contains two different sorts of data that don't belong together in a single data structure.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't worked with json builder. I have done in plain ruby, hope you can translate to builder format.

```
# Grouping all records by expense_type_id, so that we can sum
records = @expenses.group_by{ |expense| expense[:expense_type_id] }
records.map do |expense_type_id, items|
  # Initializing total as zero, so that we can sum inside loop. We can sum later in separate loop, but better to avoid many loops
  total = 0
  attributes = items.map do |item|
    bill = expense.billed.to_f
    total += bill
    {
      amount: bill, 
      id: expense.id,
      expense_type_id: expense_type_id
    }
  end
  # attributes will contain all formatted records, and lastly we insert our total
 attributes << {amount: total, id: 'Subtotal', expense_type_id: nil }
end.flatten.compact # Since we are using double map, we get array of arrays, so need to flatten
```

Answer (score 0):

I would take an Object-Oriented approach, by defining a class called `ExpenseType` (perhaps you already have this in your app, since I see a variable `expense_type_id`)...

```rb
Expense.all.group_by(&:expense_type_id).map do |type_id, expenses|
  ExpenseType.from_list(type_id,expenses).to_json
end
```

Now the array of `ExpenseType` instances can be responsible for aggregating and formatting their json representation, something like this...

```rb
# expense_type.rb
class ExpenseType
  attr_accessors :type_id, :list

  def self.from_list(type_id, list)
    new(type_id, list)
  end

  def initialize(type_id, list)
    @type_id = type_id
    @list = list
  end

  def to_json
    # skipping the detail here
    # make a json representation of the list of expenses with this expense_type_id by calling .to_json on each
    # followed by a json representation of the sum for this expense_type_id
  end
end
```

Finally each `Expense` object knows how to represent itself as json:

```rb
# expense.rb
class Expense < ApplicationRecord # I assume it's a model in a Rails app
  def to_json
    # return json representation of a single expense
  end
end
```